# dalekjs - error during installation

Tags: ubuntu, npm, dalekjs

I can not install in any way dalekjs in my project folder **/var/www/example-project/**

To install it, i'm doing next steps (in Ubuntu console):

```
andrew@andrew-Lenovo-G50-80:/var/www/example-project/src$ npm install dalekjs --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.0.9: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@1.0.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/andrew/.npm/_logs/2017-08-02T08_24_30_411Z-debug.log
andrew@andrew-Lenovo-G50-80:/var/www/example-project/src$
```

[image]

It seems like here is crutch FIX located: https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/issues/165#issuecomment-319631099

And i try do in my **package.json** so:
`"devDependencies": {
    "dalek-driver-native": "^0.0.6",
    "dalek-reporter-console": "0.0.7",
    "dalek-browser-phantomjs":"https://github.com/wrumsby/dalek-browser-phantomjs/tarball/b0b6c011eec55ea7da987461f6e1c79a6ab4bf6e"`
}`

Install going fine but when i tring to check it: `dalek -v`, there **no DalekJS local install**

[image]

No dalekjs local installed:

[image]

Please help!

Comment: The local installation finally appeared =)
Screenshot: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/JjKE/o62z7KzVy

But now i got another error while i runing my first test: **>> ERROR: dalek-driver-phantomjs: Binary not found: null**
Screenshot: https://s.mail.ru/Dvsb/NcLn2Tc4u

Comment: It seems like dalekjs is **deprecated**
I saw recomendation on dalekjs's Github - it says: "DalekJS is not maintained any longer - We recommend [http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/](TestCafé) for your automated browser testing needs."

Screenshot: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GnTx/iTN55WH4p

Comment: http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/